# How to share session variables between PHP and Angular

Tags: php, mysql, angular, session, local-storage

I have an old login system in `PHP`.

But on new sub domain we made an application with angular and I want to share login with each other, I want user to login on our subdomain and then will be redirected to my angular application.

So I need to share variables like username ,id ,full_name etc.. between both apps.

Basically I don't want to use GET request and I'm looking for something secure like may be post request or session variables or localstorage, Please guide us how we can achieve that?

Please help.. Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Usually, php sessions are managed with cookies. So change your config to also allow the session cookie for the domain your angular app runs on and it should work?

Comment: Can you tell me in more detail? I'm not able to understand